# Pandas: Group Timeseries into parts of a day

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a timeseries that I want to group into `time periods of the day`.  Grouping by hour of the day is easy:

```
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[datetime_field])
grouped = df.groupby([times.hour])
```

Now I want to group by an arbitrary number of minutes:

```
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[datetime_field])
grouped = df.groupby(['15M'])
```

I was excited to see the `TimeGrouper` class which would accept `15M`, but I don't want the timeseries resampled to be in 15 minute chunks, I want it grouped in the 'times of the day' which have a bin size of 15 minutes.

I could add a `minute_of_day` field and then use `pd.cut` to group, but that is slow and duplicates data.

Any tips are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way (among many) to achieve that:

```
df.groupby([df.ts.dt.date, df.ts.dt.hour, df.ts.dt.minute//15])
```

Explanation:

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame({'ts':pd.date_range('2016-01-01', freq='1min', periods=10000), 'col': np.random.randint(0,100, len(times))})

In [53]: df.head(10)
Out[53]:
   col                  ts
0   87 2016-01-01 00:00:00
1   89 2016-01-01 00:01:00
2   82 2016-01-01 00:02:00
3   37 2016-01-01 00:03:00
4   80 2016-01-01 00:04:00
5   24 2016-01-01 00:05:00
6   14 2016-01-01 00:06:00
7   32 2016-01-01 00:07:00
8   63 2016-01-01 00:08:00
9   81 2016-01-01 00:09:00

In [56]: df.groupby([df.ts.dt.date, df.ts.dt.hour, df.ts.dt.minute//15]).sum().head(20)
Out[56]:
                  col
ts         ts ts
2016-01-01 0  0   848
              1   716
              2   970
              3   767
           1  0   806
              1   760
              2   745
              3   678
           2  0   783
              1   722
              2   798
              3   713
           3  0   589
              1   773
              2   667
              3   796
           4  0   760
              1   735
              2   846
              3   660
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed.  From there I used get_group to pull out my individual groups.